# Desabilitar função no DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Estou tentando desativar a opção do usuário clicar na row header para que não altera a ordem dos dados na tabela porém não estou conseguindo...

Ao clicar no header de cada coluna ele reorganiza os dados e fica uma seta no canto direito (como poder ser visto no print na primeira coluna)... como poderia ser feito para desativar esta opção?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
{
    column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!